# MySQL filter, WHERE

Tags: mysql, filter

I have a problem with my mysql filter. If user has an empty field, the query doesn't work. How can I fix this, I have tried sending 'NULL' at type if type not selected, but this doesn't work too.

```
$STH = $DBH->query("
SELECT * 
WHERE store ='$type' and sdn='$status' and price>='$price_s' and price<='$price_e' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $setlimit");


$STH = $DBH->query("
SELECT * 
WHERE store ='$type' and sdn='$status' and price>='$price_s' and price<='$price_e' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $setlimit");
```

Comment: `$price_s` is numeric type?

Comment: You're SQL injecting yourself. `type=' OR 1 = 1 --` would return all your products. Let's hope that your DB class doesn't allow multiple queries or it'd be even worse: `type='; DROP TABLE store; --'`. That said, where is your `FROM` part?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the from is missing, e.g. if the table was sales, try

```
$STH = $DBH->query("
SELECT * from sales 
WHERE store='$type' and sdn='$status' and price>='$price_s' and price<='$price_e' 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $setlimit");


$STH = $DBH->query("
SELECT * from sales
WHERE store='$type' and sdn='$status' and price>='$price_s' and price<='$price_e' 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $setlimit");
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed `FROM your_table` directive

```
$STH = $DBH->query("
SELECT *
```

> FROM table

```
WHERE store ='$type' and sdn='$status' and price>='$price_s' and price<='$price_e' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $setlimit");
```

Just put the name of your table and it should work (if fields exists)